# How to get an integer value to display in a JTextfield when an element is added to a JList

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm having some trouble with my code. I have a number of lists, lists 1, 2 and 3 contain elemets so that when I click them they appear in list 4.

My goal is to have a number appear in a JTextField that will change every time an element is added to list 4.

This is the code I have in order for me to do that but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
jtextfield.setText(java.lang.String.valueOf(list4.getModel().getSize()));
```

The java.lang.String is weird I know but eclipse told me to change it.

Thank you!

Comment: You're asking "why isn't this code working?" but are not giving us the tools that would enable us to answer it. Please read the [mcve] link and then create and post one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ListDataListener`. An event will be generated any time the DefaultListModel is updated by adding or removing an item.

Then you simply invoke the code you posted above.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListDataListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listdatalistener.html) for more information and working examples.